# HaxeFlixel Puyo Puyo

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I've been wanting to make a block type game for a while now but have never understood how to actually make one. I have googled forever and there is not much and what is there comes with a stipulation that I am not wanting to bother with (gpl license, entire code base, AND the license in any project, bleh). So I took to a forums with my problem. I did not know it, but I was trying to make a Puyo Puyo type game. With blocks dropping from the ceiling and then clearing if there's a match of 3 or more. I had no idea on how to do the matching. Which is what I wanted to know. A very nice, charming, and intelligent fellow provided me with this:

http://hastebin.com/ziyejejoxu.js

Granted, that's quite a lot, but the way he managed to code it allowed me to somewhat grasp it. However, there is a single infuriating problem. One, exactly ONE, line of code does not compile and breaks. I asked him if I could email him about it and he said okay. I haven't go a response yet so I may not be getting one so I'm taking this here. Here is how I am using the code so far. There are two parts, the play state, and the puzzle piece:

http://pastebin.com/SvMR9mMb

The program breaks in the playstate, giving this error:

> source/PlayState.hx:291: characters 33-52 : Array access is not allowed on x : Int -> Int

What I have tried:

I had assumed that it was not allowed because the puzzle piece x is a float, and of course, you can't push a float into an int array. So what I did was simply in the puzzle piece first, convert the the float to an int. That did not work. THEN in the state, I switched the float to an int. That did not work. As an exercise, I attempted to convert a Flixel game to HaxeFlixel to see if I could learn anything. I probably did it wrong and did not.

So the question is: Why does that line not compile and what do I need to do to make it compile or to achieve it's intended purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is wrong. `push` is a function, and function calls use `()`. `[]` is for array access (hence the error message).

This should work:

```
if (this_piece_is_in_a_match) matched_pieces.push(_i);
```

Comment: Okay. That FINALLY compiles cleanly. Thanks. BUT I'm not seeing any change to the state. The blocks aren't being killed though. Any idea what's wrong there?

Comment: I'd just like to make a humble suggestion, and that is to start from scratch, follow the tutorials on the website, and learn the haxe syntax bit by bit. It can be nice seeing a bunch of code written for you, but in reality, you will not learn nearly as much as a very simple starter project. There are a few tutorial on the haxe website, and the docs are great. Good luck.